# UI in Graphical Layout and in device are not the same [Android]

Tags: android, xml, listview, layout

ListView in Graphical Layout is fit on appropriate height but when i imported into android device, ListView is reduced in a small field. i want ListView are the same in Graphical Layout in xml file and in real device screen

```
 <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:layout_margin="10sp"
        android:id="@+id/header"
         >
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/id"
        android:layout_weight="1.25"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/amount"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/alert"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/detail"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/android:list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="10sp"></ListView>


<RelativeLayout

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="2.5">
<Button 
     android:id="@+id/addQueue"
     android:layout_width="80dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"
     android:text="@string/addQueue"/>
 <Button 
     android:id="@+id/submit"
     android:layout_width="80dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"
     android:text="@string/submit"/>
  <Button
     android:id="@+id/reset"
     android:layout_width="80dp"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/addQueue"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_margin="10dp"
     android:text="@string/resetQueue" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to modify your layout. Try this may be it will be helpful for you.. just create a new xml layout file and check it is working for you or not.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addQueue"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/submit"
        android:text="addQueue" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/submit"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="submit" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/reset"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="resetQueue" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1.25"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="text1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="text2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="text3" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="text4" />

    </LinearLayout>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addQueue"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

My custom adapter class is here. :

```
public class my_custom_adapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    private Context context                     = null;
    String[]  elements                 = null;
    private ArrayList<Boolean> itemChecked      = null;

    public my_custom_adapter(Context context, int type, String[]  elements2)
    {
        super(context, type, elements2);
        this.elements =  elements2;
        this.context = context;
        itemChecked = new ArrayList<Boolean>();
        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                if (intent.getAction().equals("master_check_change")) {
                    boolean check_value = intent.getBooleanExtra("check_value", false);
                    set_checked(check_value);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        };
        context.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("master_check_change"));
        set_checked(false);
    }

    // AS EVERY TIME LISTVIEW INFLATE YOUR VIEWS WHEN YOU MOVE THEM SO YOU NEED TO SAVE ALL OF YOUR CHECKBOX STATES IN SOME ARRAYLIST OTHERWISE IT WILL SET ANY DEFAULT VALUE.
    private void set_checked(boolean is_checked)
    {
        for (int i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            itemChecked.add(i, is_checked);
        }
    }

    //THIS IS SIMPLY A CLASS VIEW WILL HOLD DIFFERENT VIEWS OF YOUR ROW.
    static class ViewHolder
    {
        public TextView tv;
        public CheckBox cb;
        public ImageView iv;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView (final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View rowView = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (rowView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(
                                               Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            // HERE I AM INFLATING LISTVIEW LAYOUT.
            rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inflated_layout, null, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.cb = (CheckBox) rowView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.iv = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            rowView.setTag(holder);

        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) rowView.getTag();
        }

        if (holder != null) {
            holder.tv.setText(elements[position]);

            holder.cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                             boolean isChecked) {
                    itemChecked.set(position, isChecked);
                }
            });

            if(position < itemChecked.size()) {
                holder.cb.setChecked(itemChecked.get(position));
            }
        }
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

My activity class is here where i am create custom adapter object,

```
public class Test_stflowActivity extends Activity {
    public CheckBox master_cb = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.temp_layout);
        String[] elements = new String[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            elements[i] = "elements " + i;
        }

        CheckBox master_cb = new CheckBox(getApplicationContext());
        master_cb.setText("Check All");
        //HERE IS THE LIST VIEW WHICH I HAVE CREATED IN MY XML FILE.
        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        //HERE I AM CREATING CUSTOM ADAPTER OBJECT.
        my_custom_adapter adapter = new my_custom_adapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, elements);
        lv.addHeaderView(master_cb);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
        master_cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                Intent my_intent = new Intent("master_check_change");
                my_intent.putExtra("check_value", isChecked);
                sendBroadcast(my_intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: does not work it can't be scroll list that out of list frame
i can see only 5 items

Comment: As listview is having its own scrollbar so I think it should scroll listview without scrolling button at bottom and textview as top. If you want to scroll them too with your listview then simply add bottons as footer...

Comment: I have checked it is working good... I am posting my code if you want to check. just create new project and try to make it work.